# SQL Server Group By Sets without duplicates

Tags: sql-server, performance, group-by

I need to create a "rolled up" slash "grouped" view of Customer Data for our client.

A simplified explanation would be that data need to be grouped by geographical (ex. Country, Province, City etc.) data and rolled up by the amount of people that have an email address and/or a phone number.

The problem is that a person can be in more than one Cities (lowest level) and then are counted multiple times in any higher levels (ex Province).

Here is an example using GROUPING SETS:

```
DECLARE @Customer TABLE
(
    CustomerId VARCHAR(50),
    Phone BIT,
    Email BIT,
    ProvinceId VARCHAR(50),
    CityId VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Customer(CustomerId, Phone, Email, ProvinceId, CityId) VALUES ('Customer A', 1, NULL, 'Province A', 'City A')
INSERT INTO @Customer(CustomerId, Phone, Email, ProvinceId, CityId) VALUES ('Customer A', 1, NULL, 'Province A', 'City B')
INSERT INTO @Customer(CustomerId, Phone, Email, ProvinceId, CityId) VALUES ('Customer B', 1, 1, 'Province A', 'City B')

SELECT COUNT(Phone) PersonWithPhoneCount, COUNT(Email) PersonWithEmailCount, ProvinceId, CityId FROM @Customer
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((ProvinceId), (ProvinceId, CityId))
```

and this is the result:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PersonWithPhoneCount  |  PersonWithEmailCount  |  ProvinceId  |  CityId  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                    1  |                     0  |  Province A  |  City A  |
|                    2  |                     1  |  Province A  |  City B  |
|                    3  |                     1  |  Province A  |   NULL   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The result is correct for the lowest level (City) but for the Province level "Customer A" is counted twice. I understand why, but is there a way to not count "Customer A" twice?

Do I have to group all the different levels individually or is there a better way?

Performance is also a major issue as the live data adds up to 100+ million rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, CROSS APPLY might be your saviour in this case, using TOP 1 and a group by province/city.  I am just not too sure what you mean by lowest level city.

Comment: Why would you have a customer table with the same customer in it twice? Is this data the result of a join to another table or something?

Comment: Hi Steve, it is the result of a join. We have (in the above example) 3 tables: _Customer_, _CustomerProvince_ and _CustomerCity_. Regarding your answer below, a Person can be in more than one City (and Province). The data is for example where the person has shopped. Thus there will be Persons in multiple Cities and Provinces).

Comment: Hi WickedFan, by lowest level I mean that there are other _Levels_ that I omitted from the example for simplicity. For example: Continent --> Country --> Province --> City. Thus City is the lowest _Level_. The CROSS APPLY idea opens a few doors and I will give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your data will be wrong, because there is no way Customer A can be in City A and City B, this sql will get you what you are asking for.  I used the ROW_NUMBER() function so I only count the first occurrence of the customer.

```
SELECT COUNT(Phone) PersonWithPhoneCount, COUNT(Email) PersonWithEmailCount, ProvinceId, CityId
FROM (
SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId 
            ORDER BY ProvinceId, CityId) Row
FROM @Customer c1
) Tmp
Where Row = 1
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((ProvinceId), (ProvinceId, CityId))
```